# SQL Server Audit Logs - copy current log file

Tags: sql-server, logfiles, audit-logging

How do I get SQL Server to release the current audit log file and start a new one?

We need to move our audit log files to another location, which we do nightly. However since there is little activity to log, the file rarely reaches the size at which a new one is created (according to the MAXSIZE setting). But if there is a file with content I would like to copy/move it. As we want the new location to be reasonably up-to-date I want to move whatever is available at a given time rather than whenever a file reaches the MAXSIZE setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question but have you tried using one of these tools to copy the file while it's still in use?

http://betanews.com/2013/03/25/shadowcopy-can-copy-any-file-even-if-its-locked/

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/backupcopy-files-that-are-in-use-or-locked-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but it still might be interesting for other people. I had a similar problem.
To release the log file, I created the following Script which disables the server audit and immediately enables it again.

```
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [AuditName] WITH(STATE=OFF)
GO
ALTER SERVER AUDIT[AuditName] WITH(STATE=ON)
GO
```

SQL Server then rolls the log file over. The "old" log file is then released and be moved.